# Center UIActivityIndicatorView in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've created a custom subclass of `UIImageView` and in one method I want to add an activity indicator to the center while the image is loading. I'm using the following code, but the activity monitor is positioned well outside of the `UIImageView`. What can I do to center it exactly within the bounds of the `UIImageView`?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

indicator.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

indicator.center = self.center;

[self addSubview:indicator];    
[indicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`center` property is view's coordinates in coordinate space of its **superview**. So you need to set coordinates of your indicator in the coordinate space of imageView. Correct way will be:

```
indicator.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
indicator.center = [self convertPoint:self.center fromView:[self superview]];
```

You only need to convert point because of this ([UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)):

> @property(nonatomic) CGPoint center Discussion
>
> The center is specified within the coordinate system of its **superview**
>   and is measured in points.

Answer (score 2):

`indicator.center = imageView.center;`